# Help to grab Gnome Settings Media Keys focus by "force"

Tags: gnome, 20.04, dbus, media, gnome-settings-daemon

I'm trying to create an application that listens for events sent by Gnome's **gsd-media-keys**,what I have already achieved, but other apps like VLC and Chrome are "stealing" my app’s focus when they launch.

What I realized is that these applications use a different method than the one I used in my application to ask gnome to send messages to it, and  also I realized that the method I'm using is not able to do the same(steal the focus), I can only get my application to receive the messages when none of these other applications are open(*which is very selfish, but anyway...*).

I'm doing these tests using node.js, this is the code that has the behavior that it describes up here:

```
const DBus = require('dbus');

try {
  const dbus = new DBus();
  const session = dbus.getBus('session');

  session.getInterface('org.gnome.SettingsDaemon', '/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/MediaKeys',
    'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys', (err, iface) => {
      if (!err) {
        iface.on('MediaPlayerKeyPressed', (n, keyName) => {
          console.log(n, keyName);
        });
        iface.GrabMediaPlayerKeys('Custom-Player', 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys');
      } else {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

These are the logs generated in the JournalCtl when my application connects to the dbus:

```
gsd-media-keys[134383]: Calling method 'GrabMediaPlayerKeys' for media-keys
gsd-media-keys[134383]: Registering Custom-Player at 2102244559
```

And these are the ones generated by chrome and vlc when they launch:

```
# VLC
gsd-media-keys[134383]: Updating client: index=202 name='Native client (UNIX socket client)'
gsd-media-keys[134383]: Updating client: index=202 name='VLC media player (LibVLC 3.0.9.2)'
gsd-media-keys[134383]: Creating proxy for for org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc

# Chrome
gsd-media-keys[134383]: Updating client: index=214 name='Native client (UNIX socket client)'
gsd-media-keys[134383]: Updating client: index=214 name='Chrome input'
gsd-media-keys[134383]: Creating proxy for for org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.chrome.instance139709
```

I'm trying to understand how Chrome and VLC communicate with gsd-media-keys and how I can achieve the same behavior in my application, and I'm under the impression that these two applications are not doing this through DBUS(*and I'm hesitating for now to go there in their source code to find out rs*).

Can someone help me understand what's going on or point me to some material that clarifies things a little more?
Because I'm spending a lot of time researching but I don't know where or exactly what to look for. ☹